# Looking to add some texture to my tomato soup recipe

Tags: soup, tomatoes, texture

I have been working on perfecting a tomato soup recipe for the past month or so and I've reached the point where the soup itself is to my liking.

I am now trying to figure out the garnish and so far I've decided on a dollop of creme fraiche  and a few drops of basil infused oil.

Presentation wise, the red, white and green looks fantastic, but the one element I'm missing is texture. You see, the soup is very smooth as are the creme fraiche and oil, so I'm looking to add some contrasting texture. I am at a loss of what would pair well with tomatoes. Does anyone have any suggestions to add some "crunch" to my soup?

Comment: I was about to answer "Grilled cheddar on sourdough", and then realized that you might mean in the soup rather than a pair to the soup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Croutons. They are a cinch to make at home, and just top with lemon and garlic. Or, if you are pressed for time, get some at the store.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a cliched answer, but for my money it doesn't get any better than homemade crostini. A narrow baguette, sliced 1/4 inch thick, brushed with a little olive oil or butter and toasted on a pan in the oven - yum! You can also rub a halved clove of garlic on the toasted slices for another flavor.

Answer (score 3):

Tortilla (flour or corn) strips, pan fried, make for a nice crunch that is complimentary.  They add a little crunch, but don't overwhelm.

Answer (score 2):

Bacon :o.. Or you could bake some prosciutto and crumble that on top.

Comment: Now you're talkin' :)

Answer (score 1):

Rice works well.  You can cook rice just for this purpose, but it's even more efficient to use leftover rice from the previous few days.

To top it off, add dried basil and some finely shredded cheddar to the top of the soup.

Comment: Very interesting thanks! I might give 'puffed' rice a try... the kind that are similar to Kellogg's Rice Krispies.

Answer (score 1):

I often add pulses to soups. Even after blending I find they give a delicious sort of 'grainy' texture that adds an extra dimension to the soup.
Try red lentils, or butterbeans, or even a tin of baked beans.

Answer (score 0):

Hard boiled eggs, sliced in half boats gives a nice addition to tomato soup. It's not "crunchy", but it tastes great!

Answer (score 0):

Serve it with a grilled cheese sandwich!

Answer (score -1):

Just came across your post and thought I would present a recent recipe I have tried and is getting great feedback. My [easy tomato and basil soup](http://www.gourmetmum.tv/easy-recipes/easy-tomato-and-basil-soup.html) gives great texture as I blend the roughly chopped cooked vegetables rather than the usual smooth finish.